# Weird Angularjs behavior with object into a service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a service that get an object defined into it.

```
app.factory('Store', function($http, $q){
  var obj = {
   data : [],
   load:function(params){
       var def = $q.defer();
       var count = 0;
       var nb = 0;
       while(var i<10){
           count++;
           Anotherservice.getData(i).then(function(result){
               obj.data.push(result);
               nb++;
               if(nb==count){
                     def.resolve(obj);
               }
           });
           i++;
       }
       return def.promise();
    }
 }

 return{
   load : function(params){
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       obj.load(params).then(function(dd){
           deferred.resolve(dd);
       }
       return deferred;
   }
 }
});
```

In my controller, I've got

```
Store.load("abc").then(function(stObj){
  $scope.stObj = stObj;
  console.debug($scope.stObj.data); <--- debug the array with its content correctly
  $scope.stObjData = stObj.data;
  console.debug($scope.stObjData); <--- debug the array with its content correctly
});
```

And in my view,

```
{{stObj}} -> displays the obj correctly, with obj.data as a property containing all the results.

{{stObj.data}} -> displays an empty array (while it should display data inside)
{{stObjData}} -> displays an empty array (while it should display data inside)

<div ng-repeat="res in stObj.data">
  {{res}} <-- doesn't display anything
</div>
```

I am stuck here, I don't really understand what is going on, because the stdObj is obviously not empty, is it a bug?

Comment: Sounds like that if I define obj.data = []; inside the load() function, it works correctly... weird.

Comment: You should be returning `deferred.promise` and `def.promise`, instead of `deferred` and `def.promise()`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

A new promise instance is created when a deferred instance is created and can be retrieved by calling `deferred.promise` rather than `deferred.promise()`. I created a demo for you.

<kbd>**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sua8/1/)**</kbd>